# Parse JSON from Node GET request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to output all the key/value pairs from a returned JSON feed but I'm only getting `undefined` upon logging.

Sample JSON:

```
{ entityname: 'INTERNET SOLUTIONS INC, Delinquent June 1, 2014',
    entityid: '20131032920',
    agentfirstname: 'MARTIN',
    entitystatus: 'Delinquent',
    agentprincipalcountry: 'US',
    agentprincipaladdress1: '10955 WESTMOOR DR.',
    entitytypeverbatim: 'Corporation',
    principalcountry: 'US',
    agentprincipalstate: 'CO',
    agentprincipalcity: 'WESTMINSTER',
    principaladdress1: '608 CENTER DR.',
    agentlastname: 'PELMORE',
    principalcity: 'Los Angeles',
    entityformdate: '2013-01-16T00:00:00',
    agentprincipalzipcode: '80021',
    principalstate: 'CA',
    entitytype: 'DPC',
    principalzipcode: '90045' }
```

Code I'm attempting to use:

```
const http = require('http');

http.get('http://data.colorado.gov/resource/4ykn-tg5h.json', function(res) {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    var body = "";
    var newString = "";

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d.toString();   
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        newString = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('output', newString.entityid);
    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

My expected output would be:

`entityid: '20131032920'`

For every record within the file.

Comment: That was just a mistake in the question, sorry, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON in your "sample JSON" does not match the JSON on the end of the URL.

1. Your JSON is invalid. Happily, the JSON at the URL looks OK.
2. Your JSON consists of a single object. The JSON at the URL consists of an **array** of similar objects.

`newString.entityid` is `undefined` because you are treating the array as if it were a single one of the objects inside it.

You need to pick one (or more) of the objects inside the array first.

Comment: Would I be able to use a `for` loop to loop through all the objects to print the field out for them all?

Comment: Yes. That's the normal way of doing something to every item in an array.

Comment: Got it working, didn't realise it was an array thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your online json is actually an array that contains several object. You need to select or iterate through the elements of the Array.

For example:

```
const http = require('http');

http.get('http://data.colorado.gov/resource/4ykn-tg5h.json', function(res) {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    var body = "";
    var newString = "";

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d.toString();   
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        newAry = JSON.parse(body);
        // Here the modified code, we loop across the whole JSON array.
        newAry.forEach((e) => { console.log('output', e.entityname); })
    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

will print out all the `entityname`s.